# Query result not what i want

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am running this query :

```
    select distinct(course.course) as course, count(students.studentid) as adm1,
    count(cclogs.newstudentid) from course
    left join students on (course.c_id=students.course and students.doa='2013-07-06')
    left join cclogs on (cclogs.newcid=course.c_id and doc='2013-07-06' and
    students.studentid=cclogs.newstudentid)
    where course.exampattern='2' 
    group by course.c_id
```

Now I have three tables, Student , Course and CClogs.

What I want is,  all the courses from course table, students admitted in the students table and also from the cclogs. But While am using this students.studentid=cclogs.newstudent there are no result for the coloum count(cclogs.newstudent). Any idea ?

The tables are like this :

Course

```
C_id   |   Name
 1         Abc
 2         Bcd
```

Students

```
Studentid  |   DOA         |   course
   1a        2013-07-05         Abc
   2a        2013-07-05         Bcd
   3a        2013-07-05         Bcd
   4a        2013-07-06         Abc
   5a        2013-07-05         Bcd
   6a        2013-07-06         Abc
```

CClogs

```
   id     |    newstudentid     |   oldstudentid   |   DOC      |  newcourse
    1              1b                   1a           2013-07-06      Bcd   
    2              5b                   5a           2013-07-06      Abc
```

Now when i run the query, Suppose i want result for 2013-07-06 Then the result should be like :

```
 Course     |     adm1      |       newstudentid
  Abc              2                      1
  Bcd              1                      1
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but you don't need the `DISTINCT` modifier. `GROUP BY course.c_id` should do that.

Comment: Can you add some sample data, and the desired result, and make a sqlfiddle we can experiment with?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the results that you want?  It also helps to explain why this isn't correct.

Comment: updated it fore better understanding.

Comment: Your first row has matches on the course to student, but your second doesn't (due to the date check on the JOIN). So for bcd your counts would both be 0.

Comment: So what am i supposed to do here?

Comment: How do you want to come up with the counts for bcd?

Comment: I didn't get you. I want to have newstudentid depending on the course table and doc.

Comment: But the data does not match. You only have 2 records on the students table with the date you specify, both for course abc. So adm1 will be 2 for abc and 0 for bcd. As there are no matching records for bcd on the students table, no records will be found on the cclogs table when you are matching between students and cclogs. For abc the student ids it has found a match on are 4a and 6a. Neither of those appear on cclogs, so that will give you a count of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your query a bit to try and make it clearer, and easier to understand, by aliasing the tables, and moving the filtering logic applied to the joined tables (students and cclogs) out of the from clause and into subqueries:

```
select c.course, count(s.studentid) as adm1, count(l.newstudentid) as countNew
from course c
  left join (select * from students where doa = '2013-07-06') s on c.c_id = s.course 
  left join (select * from cclogs where doc = '2013-07-06') l 
    on c.c_id = l.newcid and s.studentid = l.newstudentid
where c.exampattern='2' 
group by c.c_id
```

Now looking at what I've got here, and comparing it to your data and requirements, on the basis of just the sample data you've given, what I think is happening when your query runs is this:

the join between Course and Student happens as expected, because there are rows in the base table (Course) and rows in Students which can be correlated to courses. However when joining to ccLogs, there are no rows where newStudentID exists in Students (all of the newStudentIDs in your sample data are Bs, while all StudentIDs in Students are As) and thus the left joined ccLogs generates only null values;

when the select clause executes, it fails re the third column because for all output rows (ie each row in the course table) the ccLogs table returns nothing, and the query needs to count null.

I think the problem can be overcome as follows:

```
select c.course, count(s.studentid) as adm1, 
  sum(case when l.newstudentid is null then 0 else 1 end) as countNew
from course c
  left join (select * from students where doa = '2013-07-06') s on c.c_id = s.course 
  left join (select * from cclogs where doc = '2013-07-06') l 
    on c.c_id = l.newcid and s.studentid = l.newstudentid
where c.exampattern='2' 
group by c.c_id
```

try it and see if it works.

Hope this helps